# how to prevent re-render while using GraphQL polling

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'd need to use polling for querying data with GraphQL. But the react component should only re-render when the data has changed. How can I prevent the component from re-rendering each time new data is coming in? The following code does not prevent re-rendering.

```
  const Instructions: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<RouteParams>> = props => {
  const [firstTimeDataRender, setFirstTimeDataRender] = useState(true);
  const [instructionData, setInstructionData] = useState<FetchSettlementInstructionsQuery_instructions[]>([]);

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<FetchSettlementInstructionsQuery, FetchSettlementInstructionsQueryVariables>(
    settlementInstructionsQuery,
    {
      variables: {
        sort: null,
        filter: { type: SettlementInstructionType.freeOfPayment },
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      pollInterval: 5000,
    },
  );

  if (!!data && firstTimeDataRender) {
    setFirstTimeDataRender(false);
    setInstructionData(data.instructions);
  }

  const showLoading = loading && !(!!data && data.members) && firstTimeDataRender;

  if (data && data.instructions !== instructionData) {
    setInstructionData(data.instructions);
  }

  return (
    <LayoutContent>
      <Instructions data={instructionData} loading={showLoading} error={error ? true : false} />
    </LayoutContent>
  );
};
```

Comment: It should be related to the loading. Can You show the <Instructions /> Component?

Answer (score 0):

Your rerendering issue should be related to the loading, or the **state update** on data change. 
I would Recomend to remove the data from the state at this point. 
Im not sure if this code will work, but have removed some useless things.
If it still rerendering, Try to use Memo on the item component level:

```
const Memorized = ({ children, rerenderIfThisValueChange = true, orThis = true, id = 0 }) => useMemo(() => children, [rerenderIfThisValueChange, orThis, id]);
<Memorized orThis={instruction.smt} id={instruction.id} >
  <ListItem item={instruction} />
</Memorized>
```

and return the list items with Memorized hook.

```
const Instructions: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<RouteParams>> = props => {
      const [firstTimeDataRender, setFirstTimeDataRender] = useState(true);

      const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<FetchSettlementInstructionsQuery, FetchSettlementInstructionsQueryVariables>(
        settlementInstructionsQuery,
        {
          variables: {
            sort: null,
            filter: { type: SettlementInstructionType.freeOfPayment },
          },
          fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
          pollInterval: 5000,
        },
      );

      if (firstTimeDataRender) {
        setFirstTimeDataRender(false);
      }

      const showLoading = loading && !(!!data && data.members) && firstTimeDataRender; //  <= The problem should be here

      const { instructions = [] } = data || {}

      return (
        <LayoutContent>
          <Instructions data={instructions} loading={showLoading} error={!!error} />
        </LayoutContent>
      );
    };
```